# Length of a curve defined by a convex function

Tags: metric-geometry

Let $f \colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a function of class $C^1$ such that $f(0)=f(1)=1$ and $f'$ is nondecreasing, i.e., $f$ is convex. Show that the length of the curve defined by the graph of $f$ is less than or equal to 3.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please show what you've tried for solving the problem in order to get positive response instead of down votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intuition behind the result becomes more apparent if the graph of $f$ is adjoined with the segment between points $(0,1)$ and $(1,1)$ as to form a closed curve $\,\Gamma\,$. It is quite obvious that $\,\Gamma\,$ is a convex curve, and that it is enclosed in the unit square with opposite corners at $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. Therefore, the perimeter of $\,\Gamma\,$ can be no larger than the perimeter of the enclosing square, which is equivalent to the problem statement.

This intuition can be formalized as shown in [these](https://mathoverflow.net/a/71505) [answers](https://mathoverflow.net/a/73427) on MO, with the latter [quoting Archimedes](https://books.google.com/books?id=SHJ39945R1kC&lpg=PA88&ots=prEdYvYQaG&pg=PA88#v=onepage&f=false) for what must be the earliest formulation of the principle:

> If two plane  curves  C  and  D  with the same  endpoints  are  concave  in the same  direction,  and  C  is  included  between  D  and  the  straight line joining  the  endpoints,  then  the  length  of  C  is less  than  the  length  D.

Answer (score 2):

**Notation :** $[xy]$ is a line segment between $x$ and $y$

$[xyz]$ is a triangle whose vertexes are $x,\ y$, and $z$.

**Proof :** Assume that $f(x_0)\leq f(x)$ for all $x$

If $t_i$ is a partition s.t.
$$ A_i=(t_i,f(t_i)),\ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\ |A_i-A_{i+1}| +\varepsilon > {\rm
length \ of \ graph\ of}\ f$$

and $t_i=x_0$ for some $i$, then $$\sum_{j=1}^i\ \| A_{j-1}
 -A_j\|_1 \geq \sum_{j=1}^i\ |A_{j-1} -A_j| $$
where $\|\ \|_1$ is Manhattan distance and $$\sum_{j=i}^n\ \| A_{j}
 -A_{j+1}\|_1 \geq \sum_{j=i}^n\ |A_{j} - A_{j+1} | $$ Here $ \sum_{j}\ \| A_{j-1}
 -A_j\|_1 \leq 3$ so that the prooof is followed.

**Proof using Euclidean distance :** For convenience, we assume that $f(\frac{1}{2}=x_0)=0$.

Then consider $$ S:=\bigg\{ (0,t)\bigg|0\leq t\leq 1\bigg\} \cup \bigg\{ (t,0) \bigg|0\leq
t\leq \frac{1}{2} \bigg\} ,\ T:=\sum_{j=1}^i\ [A_{j-1} A_j] $$$$
Consider a region $R$ enclosed by $S\cup T$. We cut $R$ into $R_2$
and a piece $Q_2$. We cut $R_2$ into $R_3$ and $Q_3$. If we repeat
the process, so $R_i$ goes to $T$ in Hausdorff distance.

Here we can assume that all $Q_i=[a_ib_ic_i]$ are triangle with
$[b_ic_i]\subset R_i$. Since $$ |a_i-b_i|+|a_i-c_i|\geq |b_i-c_i|$$

so length of $\partial R_i-T$ is decreasing.